# What should be done when users remove relevant tags from the question?

Tags: discussion, edits

There are many cases where users edit out certain tags from a question. This might perhaps be done with good intention in mind, but when other users disagree with the removal of the tag(s), they add it back. Most of the times, this would go unnoticed, but in some cases, it develops into an edit war. Sometimes, this goes as much as required to make the post into a  Community Wiki.

For example, take a look at [this revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/23236303/revisions). The question is clearly related to MySQLi and it was tagged [mysqli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysqli), but it was edited out by a user. Later, another user found this question and added the tag again. Here's [another example](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/23084109/revisions).

What's the best way to handle such cases? Does it really warrant a moderator attention flag?

**Note:** This question is not specifically about the two linked questions. I'm looking for general suggestions.

Comment: Note that this won't force them to CW anymore.

Comment: What won't? Who is "them", @TheGuywithTheHat?

Comment: Edit wars won't turn posts into community wikis: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/04/putting-the-community-back-in-wiki/

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat: Great news! I hadn't read that blog post.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Not all things that appear in a question are necessarily relevant tags.

The question in your first example is not really about mysqli. It just happens to be the database layer that the OP uses to show his query. It has no relevance to the question.

The user was right to edit it out.

In the second example, the case is not as clear - the argument could be made that the `pdo`  tag should stay. Although the argument could *also* be made that it isn't a PDO-specific issue... I personally would have left it in place, but removed `mysql`.

If a user insists on a tag edit and you *really* feel it is damaging the question - even when taking into consideration the points above - then I guess calling for mod attention is in order.

Comment: What about [these edits](http://bpaste.net/show/uHSIoA5T2AgNIbepnc0x/)? Some of these edits are a bit borderline and there's no harm in leaving those tags around. But some users insist on the tag being removed and will continue doing so forever. What should be done in such situations?

Comment: "_then I guess calling for mod attention is in order_", @AmalMurali

Comment: @Mat: I was thinking maybe somehow we could resolve the issues *without* bugging the mods, but it seems there's no other solution here.

Comment: It's a mixed bag, @AmalMurali. Many of those edits are ok, as the technology used in the tag has nothing to do with the actual question... in other cases, I feel he's going overboard removing `pdo` where it really should stay. Mod flagging seems like the only way to go there